# Count Array Elements Matching Condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection in MongoDB and their objects look like this:

Object 1

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5afde62a91952a2980a1b751"),   
    "notificationName" : "Teste Agendamento Pontual",
    "messages" : [ 
        {
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-05-17T20:29:33.045Z"),            
            "message" : "Teste Agendamento Pontual"
        }, 
        {
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-05-17T20:29:33.051Z"),            
            "message" : "Teste"
        }, 
        {
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-05-17T20:29:44.680Z"),            
            "message" : "OK"
        }        
    ]
}
```

Object 2

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5afde62a9194322980a1b751"),   
    "notificationName" : "Teste Agendamento Pontual",
    "messages" : [ 
        {
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-05-17T20:29:33.045Z"),            
            "message" : "Teste Agendamento Pontual"
        }, 
        {
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-05-17T20:29:33.051Z"),            
            "message" : "NOT OK"
        }, 
        {
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-05-17T20:29:44.680Z"),            
            "message" : "asdsadasd"
        }        
    ]
}
```

...

I'm trying to get a result grouped by **notificationName** with a count of objects with **OK** messages and other count with objects with **NOT OK** .
I think I need to make a $cond in $group to check **message** property, but I'm not sure about that. And not sure if thats the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

If you want matching array elements then you want [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) instead and count them using [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$notificationName",
    "countOk": {
      "$sum": {
        "$size": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$messages.message",
            "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$this", "OK" ] }
          }
        } 
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

The [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) has it's own `cond` argument which is a logical condition to return a boolean value determining whether the array element matches that condition or not and can be returned. Since this would only then return an array of values from `message` where the value is `"OK"` using the [`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) comparison operator to test, then you "count" the resulting array members using [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/).

Because you are "grouping" you use [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) as the stage to do this, and because you are "accumulating" you use the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) operator to "add up" all the returned [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) results from each document sharing the same grouping key